# how to get hour and minute from timepicker in android

Tags: java, android, timepicker

This is code I got for TimePicker.

### TimePicker.java

```
public class TimePicker extends EditText implements
    android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
public interface OnTimeSetListener {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute);
}

protected int hour;
protected int minute;
protected OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener;
protected java.text.DateFormat timeFormat;

public int getHour() {
    return hour;
}

public OnTimeSetListener getOnTimeSetListener() {
    return onTimeSetListener;
}

public void setOnTimeSetListener(OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener) {
    this.onTimeSetListener = onTimeSetListener;
}

public void setHour(int hour) {
    this.hour = hour;
    updateText();
}

public int getMinute() {
    return minute;
}

public void setNow() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    setTime(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
}

public void setMinute(int minute) {
    this.minute = minute;
    updateText();
}

public void setTime(int hour, int minute) {
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    updateText();
}

public TimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getContext());

    setInputType(InputType.TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_DATE);
    setFocusable(false);
    setNow();
}

protected void showTimePicker() {
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

    timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), this, getHour(),
            getMinute(), true);
    timePickerDialog.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        showTimePicker();

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public java.text.DateFormat getTimeFormat() {
    return timeFormat;
}

public void setTimeFormat(java.text.DateFormat timeFormat) {
    this.timeFormat = timeFormat;
    updateText();
}

@Override
public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setTime(hour, minute);
    clearFocus();

    if (onTimeSetListener != null){
        onTimeSetListener.onTimeSet(this, hour, minute);
    }

}

public void updateText() {
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(0, 0, 0, getHour(), getMinute());
    setText(timeFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
}
```

}

### calendar_events.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/maroon"
    tools:context="com.gpplsmje.mac.calendar.CalendarEvents" >

    <com.gpplsmje.mac.calendar.utils.TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/alarm_time"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

### CalendarEvents.java

```
public class CalendarEvents extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TimePicker notifyTime;

Button back, cancel, done;
int hour, minute, day, month, year;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.calendar_events);
    onNewIntent(getIntent());

    notifyTime = ((TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarm_time));
    notifyTime.setTimeFormat(DateFormat.getTimeFormat(this));

    hour = notifyTime.getHour();
    minute = notifyTime.getdMinute();

    done.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.bDone:
        Toast.makeText(this, year + " " + month + " " + day + " " + hour + " " + minute , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

I made a `Toast` message to check if what I have selected from the `TimePicker` is the right thing. But every time I run this code it always gives me the current time on my machine and not the time I selected from the `TimePicker`. How do I accomplish this? Can any one please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use this method `setOnTimeChangedListener(TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener onTimeChangedListener)`

and this class when working with timepicker.  [timepicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener.html)

not onclick listener on it..

Comment: thanks.. so from the code above where do I place it? in TimePicker.java or in CalendarEvents.java?

Comment: In your calendar event class

Answer (score 2):

If you clear focus from the TimePicker in your `onClick()` handler, you can use its public [methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#getCurrentHour%28%29) to get the selected time values as integers:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    ...
    notifyTime = ((TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarm_time));
    notifyTime.clearFocus();

    hour = notifyTime.getCurrentHour();
    minute = notifyTime.getCurrentMinute();
    ....
}
```

Comment: I don't have a getCurrentHour() and getCurrentMinute() in my TimePicker Class. what's supposed to be inside it?

Comment: how would I implement the getCurrentHour() and getCurrentMinute() methods in my TimePicker.java.?

Comment: instead of extending `EditText`, you could use Android's `TimePicker` to expose these methods:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html

Answer (score 0):

To read the time entered by the user, Use a listener

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mHour = hourOfDay;
            mMinute = minute;
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };
```

Comment: thanks.. so from the code above where do I place it? in TimePicker.java or in CalendarEvents.java?

Answer (score 0):

This way you can get the time

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

 mHour = mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
 mMinute = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

 TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(mActivity, mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, false);

 private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
     public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

         mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
         mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mMinute);
         SimpleDateFormat mSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
         String time = mSDF.format(mCalendar.getTime());
     }
 }
```